# PyCharm won't accept code completion on enter

Tags: python, pycharm, code-completion

since yesterday PyCharm 2016.3 won't accept selected lines from the list of code completion:

If I hit enter, a new line will be set into the editor rather than the selected line of the popup window. Is there any setting for this behaviour? Until now I couldn't find anything.

Comment: You should upload images using the tool in the editor, images hosted on external sources aren't rendered on Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 0):

I noticed on a few occasions the GUI going somehow off-rails, including in ways similar to the one described. I couldn't determine a pattern in the occurences. Just closing and re-opening the project didn't always help.

What worked pretty reliably for me in the end was exiting PyCharm (giving it ample time to finish), making sure no related java processes remains active (running on Linux, in some cases I had to manually kill such processes when it became clear they're not going away by themselves) and then re-starting the IDE.

Comment: Thanky, but even this and a reboot did not helped, but I found the keymap by chance.

Answer (score 0):

I found the current keymap for code completion by chance. This is set via:

```
Settings > Keymap > Code > Completion > Basic
```

Comment: For Pycharm 2017.x:
    Settings > Keymap > Main menu > Code > Completion > Basic